# Titan antenna VSWR and radio problem

Tags: antenna, impedance-matching, equipment-troubleshooting

I just installed a new [Titan DX antenna](http://gapantenna.com/shop/antennas/titan-dx/) and I am using psk31 with fldigi.  When I transmit on 20m at 14072, the SWR is 1.65 and it shuts off my computer and the radio keeps transmitting.

However, on 40m at 7025 the SWR is 2.0, and it works fine.  I can't figure this out?

Comment: Hello Thomas, and welcome to this site! Are you measuring the SWR directly at the antenna, or indoors near your radio? Also, what radio are you using? Kindly [edit your question](https://ham.stackexchange.com/posts/18626/edit) to include these details, so that others are better able to help you.

Comment: That sounds like you may have a RF leak when you're transmitting from what you've said.  I would suggest making sure your coax connections are tight and ensuring you have a good ground on your radio and antenna.

Could you give more information to help us such as make and model of your radio, what type of coax you're using, and how much power you're using to transmit?

Comment: Thomas, please tell us about the connections between the computer and the radio.